Latency issue - How to perfectly sync audio beeps (using Web Audio API) and visualization (using canvas + requestAnimationFrame)?
I use an audioContext = new AudioContext() of the Web Audio API for scheduling beep sounds for every beat (relative to a user-defined bpm and time signature) - let's call this stack of beeps "track".
Simultaneously I would like to visualize this track on a canvas which get's re-rendered each animationFrame:

The task is to synchronize audio and visuals - there are 2 issues with this:

time → timing-wise we can make combine 3 different clocks (currentTime in Audio API thread, setInterval in main thread and animationFrames for rendering visuals) as described in this article - so no real problem in this regard
latency → even though you can schedule a sound very precisely using sth. like audioContext.createOscillator().start(audioContext.currentTime + 1) this doesn't mean that the user hears the sound immediately, since there is some latencies which delay the actual sound output in the user's audio device.

I was trying a lot of things and reading many articles about this but am still puzzled on how to properly deal with these latencies:

I know already that when using sourceBuffers I'd have to load them first
I believe that I should take audioContext.baseLatency into consideration(?) → maybe after having created the audioContext I should delay starting both audio and visuals by audioContext.baseLatency seconds?***
audioContext.outputLatency seems to be the crucial aspect as it seems to tell sth about the time between a) the scheduled start time and b) the audio device starting to process the received buffer?
But: Even though on my machine the outputLatency is ~0.04s the actual sound delay seems much higher - more like tripled.*
I read here that there are some catches with outputLatency, from drivers just lying about its value to all sorts of uncertainties..

I would like to know if there is a solid way of either retrieving the actual time descrepancy between a)** scheduled start time and b) the time the user will hear the beep, or if there is a different approach I could take in order to synchronize audio and visuals.
*) Tested in 3 ways:

simply by hearing and watching
recording the screen, then playing it back in slomo to see where the red line is when hearing a beep
By listening to the "ended" event of the oscillator and checking audioContext.currentTime against the expected/calculated end time of the scheduled beep
I don't know if this is a good approach for testing latency(?)

**) Maybe there is a way to detect when sound is played from the user's audio device? Then match that time against the expected start time?
***) Acutually baseLatency only affects the start of the first beep, after this all following scheduled beeps will be processed w/o delay (by the Audio API - the outputLatency is unrelated to this)
Update: This is how I tested baseLatency and found out that when scheduling multiple sounds (i.e. in 1s, in 2s, in 3s) only the first sound's buffer processing is late by exactly audioContext.baseLatency, whereas all following sounds come without latency:
class Processor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options)
    this.started = false
  }

  process(inputs) {
    if (!this.started && inputs[0]?.[0]?.[0]) {
      this.port.postMessage('started')
      this.started = true
    } else if (this.started && !inputs[0]?.[0]?.[0]) {
      this.port.postMessage('finished')
      this.started = false
      // return false
    }
    return true
  }
}

registerProcessor('processor', Processor)

Thanks a lot in advance for any hints into the right direction!

The time (in relation to currentTime) it takes for the audio to leave the Web Audio API and to arrive at your audio output device is the baseLatency plus the outputLatency.
The baseLatency describes the size of the internal buffer used by the Web Audio API to play through small performance glitches. It's for example always 0 in Firefox because it has no such buffer. This value should always be correct because the Web Audio API is in full control of it.
The outputLatency on the other hand is the amount of time it takes for the audio to reach the audio output device. It is dependent on how the operating system works and on the audio output device itself. The browser relies on the operating system to get this number.
If you play something at 3 seconds it will be heard at 3 seconds + baseLatency + outputLatency.

Thx for your answer! I understood the theory of both latencies (I think), but as described the reality doesn't always match with it - at least not with outputLatency. On one computer (MacOS, Chrome browser, wire earphones) the value of outputLatency is low but I hear the sound much later than that. So I was wondering if there was a way to automatically detect this descrepancy. A workaround would be to offer our users a calibration tool where they can tune until they think sound and visuals are perfectly in sync. Wrt baseLatency: The delay only applies to the first scheduled sound - see update

Maybe a tool like this (https://padenot.github.io/roundtrip-latency-tester/) can help you to figure out if the numbers reported for your system are correct.
